# why cant i create image file(jpg) copy using text editor or using C program?

Tags: c, image

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc , char **argv)
{
  FILE *fp1 = fopen(argv[0] , "r");   
  FILE *fp2;  

  fseek(fp1 , 0L , SEEK_END);

  long int file_size = ftell(fp1);    

  printf("file size is : %ld\n", file_size);   

  rewind(fp1);    

  int cnt = 0;

  fp2 = fopen("newImage.jpg", "w"); 

  printf("file pointer is at %ld ", ftell(fp1));  

  while(cnt < file_size) {
    fputc( fgetc(fp1), fp2 ); 
    cnt++;  
  }

  fclose(fp1);    
  fclose(fp2);    

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;    
}
```

Comment: Open the file for both reading an writing in binary mode `rb` and `wb`

Comment: @StoryTeller  replaced with `rb` and `wb` still not working

Comment: What has `str` to do with it? Why allocate memory you do not use?

Comment: `argv[0]` is program name. you want `argv[1]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane updated . previously used forgot to delete

Comment: @BLUEPIXY silliest mistake. its working.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  can you tell why it doesn't work if i opened it in text editor  and copied it in another file and tried to open it as *jpg?

Comment: It is not text. A text editor might possibly alter what it believes are "line endings."

Comment: In general, characters that can not be displayed with a text editor are changed when saving.

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered from the comments, `argv[0]` is what burned you, technically.  I wanted to offer some advice that would have saved you the trouble of posting to SO.

For anything posted to a public forum, it's advisable to format the code "correctly", as an aid to anyone who'll take the time to answer you.  The better they understand what you're doing, and the more care you've taken with your question, the better answers you'll get.

For simple programs like this, it's useful to *recapitulate the input*.  When you print the file size, print the name, too.  You would have seen immediately you were copying the wrong file.

For any program, especially in C, and very especially where there's I/O involved, it's *essential* to check return codes for syscalls.  **assert**(3) and **err**(3) are your friends here.  Notably, if you don't check for EOF from **fgetc**, you stand to write -1 to every byte of the output file, with nary a message to the user.  (Yes, you have every right to expect that if you can open and seek on a file, you'll be able to read from it.  OTOH, a tiny mistake like reading from `fp2` could go unnoticed.)

Strange as it may seem, careful error checking encourages writing minimal code.  In your case, you really don't care how big the file is.  You just want to read all the input, until EOF.  If you do that, you naturally adopt the idiom `while( (ch = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF )` and save yourself a call to find out how big the file is.

Get to know **getopt**(3) and use it.  That would have saved you stumbling on `argv[0]`.

If you follow that advice, you may find as I have that more often than not the question answers itself.  C is a simple language, and the C standard library is well documented.  If you're careful about your inputs, fastidious in formatting, and relentless in checking for errors, the only mistakes left will be in your logic.  Which is how you want it.  :-)